# A word for improper, but not sexual, interest

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes I find myself being curious about or reading through personal or internet drama, not out of true concern to the parties involved, but because it's entertaining. I find this somewhat shameful, because the issues are serious to others and not to me.

I am looking for something like "morbidly curious" without the connotations of death, or a "prurient" or "voyeuristic" interest without sexual connotations. I've used "indecorous" before, but I was wondering if there might be something more idiomatic. The part of speech it fills is not important to me, but ideally it would be something like:

> Sorry if I'm being ____ [or my question is ____], but what did he say next?

Comment: ***Inquisitive***? -*wanting to discover as much as you can about things, sometimes in a way that annoys people*

Comment: "Intrusive" or "impertinent" could work depending on the context. "Impertinent" suggests that the person asking the question has lower status while "intrusive" suggests a more equal or reversed relationship.

Comment: @BoldBen I really like "impertinent"!

Comment: How does **curious** sound?

Answer (score 3):

**Prying**

Sorry if I’m prying - but what happens next?

Definition:

excessively interested in a person's private affairs; too inquisitive.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pry

Comment: +1  Or "I don't mean to pry, but what happened next?"

Answer (score 0):

Adjective **nosy** and noun **nosiness** refer to curiosity about things you have no business to know. The connotation is of sticking your nose into something that doesn't concern you. They are perhaps slightly informal, although not sufficiently informal to be tagged as such in dictionaries.

[Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosy) defines **nosy** as "of prying or inquisitive (see INQUISITIVE sense 2) disposition or quality : INTRUSIVE". Example phrases are "nosy reporters" and "nosy neighbors". The noun **nosiness** and adverb **nosily** are derived from this.

It fits well into a sentence like "Sorry if I'm being nosy, but what did he say next?"